# Edge evaluates @supports(mask) as true when mask isn't supported

Tags: css

Edge doesn't support [CSS mask](https://caniuse.com/#search=mask), yet the `@supports` statement below is calculating as `true` and the enclosed styles are being applied in Edge. What can I put into the `@supports` argument to get Edge to ignore the conditional block

```css
body {
  font-family: monospaced;
  color: red;
  background-image: url(test.png);
}

@supports(mask: url("")) {
  body {
    background-color: #eee;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: rebeccapurple;
    mask: url(test.svg);
    mask-size: cover;
  }
}
```

```html
<h3>This should be red and mono-spaced in Edge</h3>
```

Comment: Don't know why it evaluates `true` but maybe you could combine your @supports rule with something that EDGE does not support yet, like `@supports (mask: url("")) and (font-variant-numeric: ordinal) { } `

Comment: It certainly works and I had thought of that, but can't add the tech debt at the end of the day. It pushes the snooze button on something to break further down the road.

Comment: As of Edge 17 I was getting false positives for `@supports (mask: url(""))` as well as `@supports (mask-image: url(""))`. I built a [pen](https://codepen.io/absolutholz/pen/WmBKVZ) to test and rule out various combinations of file inclusions (external uri vs base64), file types (svg vs png) and @supports checks. My solution was to check `@supports(mask-repeat: no-repeat) {}` which allows me to use a fallback for IE and Edge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Edge API docs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/catalog/?q=specName%3Acss-masking-1), `mask` is supported, but since I'm ultimately just looking for support of a mask image, I can do:

```
@supports(mask-image: url("")) {
  body {
    …
    mask-image: url(test.svg);
    …
  }
}
```

Cleaner and more specific.

The docs mention that a `maskImage` style property is supported, but I can't get that to work.

Answer (score 0):

Now that Chrome (and Chromium browsers such as Edge) support [inspection of `@supports` rules via DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-100/#supports), it can be clearly seen in Edge 100 that `mask-image` is not supported.

Here is a screenshot

[image: screenshot-1]

using

```
@supports (display: flex) or (mask-image: url("")) {}
```

and you can see the highlighted button has a green `background-color`. Inspecting in DevTools shows all the elements and rules applied - also see (in the red box) how the `background-color` not in the `@supports` rule is overwritten.

However, when I change the rule to

```
@supports (mask-image: url("")) {}
```

the button is now orange/black b/c the `@supports` condition is no longer being met.

[image]

Clearly, `mask-image` is not supported by Edge.